# How a cookies will maintain session state?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-state

Cookies allow your applications to store a small amount of textual data (typically,
4-6kB) on a Web client. There are a number of possible uses for cookies, although
their most common one is maintaining session state.Cookies are typically set by the server using a response header, and subsequently made available by the client as a request header.

this is from zce study guide.

My questions are

```
1. how a session state is maintained by cookie?
2. what happens to these cookies when we use session_destroy()?
```

Comment: This is pretty well covered in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Comment: +1 for the above comment, you really should have just searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, the session cookie ties a remote session to your browser as you navigate a given site. It contains a string usually along the lines of `PHPSESSID=3432DFGDFG43523` which the remote server identifies as a session that it is managing.

From the PHP website:

> A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the
>   so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user
>   side or is propagated in the URL.
>
> The session support allows you to store data between requests in the
>   $_SESSION superglobal array. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP
>   will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on
>   your request (explicitly through session_start() or implicitly through
>   session_register()) whether a specific session id has been sent with
>   the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is
>   recreated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

When `session_destroy()` is called, it doesn't quite behave as you'd expect. The session is destroyed remotely but the local cookie isn't removed. To do this you'd need to call `setcookie(<session cookie name>)` with a negative date to destroy it on the client side. Again, from the PHP website:

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables
>   again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: so when we request for a page will all these cookies will be sent to server in through request headers

Answer (score 1):

Very short:

A session id is created which is sent over to the client on each request, this is stored in a cookie usually called PHPSESSID. The client responds with this session id to tell the server which session it belongs to.

session_destroy only unsets the data, not the identity. So cookies are not touched using that method.

Comment: so when we request for a page will all the cookies will be sent to server through request headers

Comment: Only the identifier, not the cookies. :)